# Scala code to label rows of data frame based on another data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just started learning scala to do data analytics and I encountered a problem when I try to label my data rows based on another data frame.

Suppose I have a `df1` with columns `"date","id","value",`and`"label"` which is set to be `"F"` for all rows in `df1` in the beginning. Then I have this `df2` which is a smaller set of data with columns `"date","id","value"`.Then I want to change the row label in df1 from `"F"` to `"T"` if that row appears in `df2`, i.e.some row in df2 has the same combination of `("date","id","value")`as that row in `df1`.

I tried with `df.filter` and `df.join` but seems that both cannot solve my problem.

Comment: what have you done so far can you share?

Comment: what dataframes are you using? spark?

Comment: yes I'm using spark! thanks of the answers, both are helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think this is what you are looking for.

```
val spark =SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
      //create Dataframe 1
    val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("2016-01-01", 1, "abcd", "F"),
      ("2016-01-01", 2, "efg", "F"),
      ("2016-01-01", 3, "hij", "F"),
      ("2016-01-01", 4, "klm", "F")
    )).toDF("date","id","value", "label")

  //Create Dataframe 2
  val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("2016-01-01", 1, "abcd"),
    ("2016-01-01", 3, "hij")
  )).toDF("date1","id1","value1")

  val condition = $"date" === $"date1" && $"id" === $"id1" && $"value" === $"value1"

  //Join two dataframe with above condition
  val result = df1.join(df2, condition, "left")

//  check wather both fields contain same value and drop columns 
  val finalResult = result.withColumn("label", condition)
    .drop("date1","id1","value1")
//Update column label from true false to T or F
  finalResult.withColumn("label", when(col("label") === true, "T").otherwise("F")).show
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to join the two and then calculate the result. Something like this:

```
df2Mod = df2.withColumn("tmp", lit(true))
joined = df1.join(df2Mod , df1("date") <=> df2Mod ("date") && df1("id") <=> df2Mod("id") && df1("value") <=> df2Mod("value"), "left_outer")
joined.withColumn("label", when(joined("tmp").isNull, "F").otherwise("T")
```

The idea is that we add the "tmp" column and then do a left_outer join. "tmp" would be null for everything not in df2 and therefore we can use that to calculate the label.